# ¿Comó puedo hacer que salga una ventana pandastable con los datos del dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Al apretar el botón "Visualizar" debería salir una ventana con los datos de `df`
Si alguien me podría ayudar estaré muy agradecido

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from pandastable import Table, TableModel, config

class FormularioBolsa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1=tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("Predicción de precios")
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)        
        self.sp_500()
        self.formula()
        self.listado_completo()
        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()
        Frame.__init__(self)
        

    def sp_500(self):
        #title
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text="Primeros tickets SP500")
        #LabelFrame
        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="Tickets")        
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=50, pady=10)
        #Combobox-Símbolo
        self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Símbolo:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.simbolo=tk.StringVar()
        self.combo=ttk.Combobox(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.simbolo, state="readonly")
        self.combo.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        lista = self.aleatorios()
        self.combo["values"]= lista
        #Label-StartDate
        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Start-Date:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.sdate=tk.StringVar()
        self.entryprecio=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.sdate)
        self.entryprecio.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Label-EndDate
        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="End-Date:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.edate=tk.StringVar()
        self.entryprecio=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.edate)
        self.entryprecio.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Botón Aleatorio
        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="AleatorioP", command = self.aleatorios)
        self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Botón Visualizar
        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Visualizar", command = self.datos)
        self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Frame
        self.scrolledtext2=st.ScrolledText(self.pagina1, width=65, height=18)
        self.scrolledtext2.grid(column=0,row=5, padx=15, pady=15)

    def aleatorios(self):
        lista = []
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(si.tickers_sp500())
        dfA = df1.sample(n=10)
        lista = list(dfA[0])
        return lista

    def datos(self):
        #Datos
        ticker = 'AMZN'
        start_date = '2022-03-21'
        end_date = '2022-06-21'
        df = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)
        #Ventana
        self.f = Frame(self.)
        self.f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.table = pt = Table(self.f, dataframe=df,showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        pt.show()
        return
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es que no estas creando una nueva ventana para mostrar la tabla

Ejemplo creando una nueva ventana en el método `datos` (**Nota:** Tuve que comentar algunas cosas de tu código ya que en la sección que agregaste no estaban definidas algunas cosas)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from pandastable import Table, TableModel, config

class FormularioBolsa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1=tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("Predicción de precios")
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)        
        self.sp_500()
        #self.formula()
        #self.listado_completo()
        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()
        Frame.__init__(self)
        

    def sp_500(self):
        #title
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text="Primeros tickets SP500")
        #LabelFrame
        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="Tickets")        
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=50, pady=10)
        #Combobox-Símbolo
        self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Símbolo:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.simbolo=tk.StringVar()
        self.combo=ttk.Combobox(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.simbolo, state="readonly")
        self.combo.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        lista = self.aleatorios()
        self.combo["values"]= lista
        #Label-StartDate
        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Start-Date:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.sdate=tk.StringVar()
        self.entryprecio=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.sdate)
        self.entryprecio.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Label-EndDate
        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="End-Date:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.edate=tk.StringVar()
        self.entryprecio=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.edate)
        self.entryprecio.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Botón Aleatorio
        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="AleatorioP", command = self.aleatorios)
        self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Botón Visualizar
        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Visualizar", command = self.datos)
        self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        #Frame
        self.scrolledtext2=st.ScrolledText(self.pagina1, width=65, height=18)
        self.scrolledtext2.grid(column=0,row=5, padx=15, pady=15)

    def aleatorios(self):
        lista = []
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(si.tickers_sp500())
        dfA = df1.sample(n=10)
        lista = list(dfA[0])
        return lista

    def datos(self):
        #Datos
        ticker = 'AMZN'
        start_date = '2022-03-21'
        end_date = '2022-06-21'
        df = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)
        
        #Nueva ventana
        newWindow = Toplevel(self.ventana1)
        newWindow.title("Nueva ventana")
        newWindow.geometry("800x800")

        self.table = Table(newWindow, dataframe=df,showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        self.table.show()
        return

a = FormularioBolsa()
```

Al oprimir el botón "Visualizar" aparece la siguiente ventana:

[image: Ventana]